# ClassCastException in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I am new to clojure and i have been trying out different programs. Here is my program :

```
(defn sdsu-reverse [x]
  (loop [n (count x) x x]
  (if (= 0 n)
    (x)
    (recur (- n 1) (conj (next x) (first x))))))

(= (sdsu-reverse [1 2 3 4 5]) [5 4 3 2 1])
```

I have been getting error : java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
C:\Users\Shalima\Documents\Textbooks\Functional Programming\Programs\sample.clj:44 user/sdsu-reverse

But I cant seem to figure it out. Could you please help me with this ?

Thank you.

Comment: `(x)` tries to call `x` (which is a sequence) as a function. All you need there is `x`.

Comment: Also (since you're learning) you don't need to count your sequence every time. You just want to check if it's empty.

Comment: @DiegoBasch Indeed you just want to check if it's empty, but note that the original code only counts it once, not every time.

Comment: Correct, I thought I saw a count in the comparison. The OP's code (as it is now at least) counts at the start of the loop. It does keep an unnecessary counter though.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex notes above, you need to replace `(x)` with `x` in your if expression. Wrapping x in parentheses treats it as a function when instead you want to return a value.

As for the other issue in your code:

`conj` is a slightly confusing function.

```
clojure.core/cons
([x seq])
  Returns a new seq where x is the first element and seq is
    the rest.
```

Sounds clear enough. But look at what happens when `conj` is applied to a list versus a vector ([source](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/conj)).

```
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 4)
[1 2 3 4]

user=> (conj '(1 2 3) 4)
(4 1 2 3)
```

The reason for this has to do with how the vector and list datatypes are constructed. Vectors receive new values from the righthand side; lists, from the lefthand side.

When you call `conj (next x) (first x)`, you effectively are calling `conj '(2 3 4) '(1)`, over and over again. So you end up with the same value that you started at.

A better approach would be to use recursion as follows.

```
(defn sdsu-reverse [x]
  (if (empty? x)
    nil
    (cons (last x) (sdsu-reverse (drop-last x)))))
```

I hope this helps.

**Edit** in response to Leonid's comments.

Leonid is correct that the above will fail for large sequences. Alternatively you could do something like

```
(defn reverse' 
  ([x] (reverse' x nil))
  ([x acc] (if (empty? x) 
             acc 
             (recur (rest x) (cons (first x) acc)))))
```

Comment: Using `recur` is always better than using direct recursion, not only because it's **much** faster, but also because direct recursion leads to stack overflow. Try reversing something like `(range 99999)` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Using `last` and `drop-last` instead of `first` and `rest` is also a very bad idea, because they are extremely ineffective when applied to sequences.

Comment: Agreed. Amended my answer.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: the simplest and the most efficient way to revert a sequence is to use `reduce` higher-order function: `(reduce conj () x)`, which is exactly how build-in `reverse` function works.

Answer (score 0):

class cast exception in your code is because you try to make a list from a constant 
i.e. (x) so just replace it with x you won't get class cast exception.